# WindowsServer 2008 - Temporary ASP.NET files

Tags: asp.net

In Windows Server 2008, I see compiled binaries land in "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files" instead of "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files". 
WHats the reason and what should be done to make the binaries land in 64 bit version ?

/Sam

Answer (score 1):

Sam-

Are you running your ASP.NET application in a 32-bit application pool? If so, it will run as a 32-bit process and will thus use the non-64-bit temporary asp.net files folder.